# How do I set where my grails plugins should be installed?

Tags: windows, grails, plugins

I saw the light and install the joda-time plugin for grails.

However, when I tried to commit my changes to source control I realised that grails had located the files in:

```
C:\Users\Steve\.grails\1.1.1\plugins
```

instead of somewhere under the project directory of:

```
f:\grails\projects\myproject
```

Yeah I'm using windows :-\

So now when someone pulls down my changes from source control they are missing all the joda-time plugin lovelyness and they are wanting to spank me :)

What should I be setting so that grails doesn't put anything under my user directory?
(It isn't installed as a global plugin - just as a project one - at least I think so, I ran "grails install-plugin joda-time" )

Many thanks in advance.

P.S. Currently listening to Plug In Baby by Muse....how coincidental :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin is listed in application.properties, so when someone gets your code Grails will install missing plugins the first time they run 'grails run-app' or other commands.

If you want to revert to 1.0.x behavior just create grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy with the line

```
grails.project.plugins.dir='plugins'
```

and your plugins will be in with the rest of the project files.

Comment: Thanks. He just needed to rebuild his project as well.